# Message: Trying to get property of non-object when get ID

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a simple  update data. I get the following error PHP notice after it:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: belanja/ubah.php
>
> Line Number: 29

This is my controller

```
public function ubah($id){
        $data = array();
        $data['msg']            = $this->_get_flashdata();
        $data['category']       = $this->m_category->get(); 
        $data['notif']          = $this->m_property->count_properti();
        $data['notifikasi']     = $this->m_property->notif_properti();
        $data['rows']           = $this->m_property->getByID($id);

        $html = array();
        $html['header']     = $this->load->view('admin/header',$data,true);
        $html['kiri']       = $this->load->view('admin/kiri',null,true);
        $html['content']    = $this->load->view('admin/belanja/ubah',$data,true);
        $this->load->view('admin/template',$html);
    }
```

This is my model

```
public function getByID($id){
            $sql= "SELECT * FROM properti WHERE nID = '".$id."'";
            return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
        }
```

And this is my view

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                            <h4 class="header green clearfix">
                                Nama Properti
                            </h4>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nama" value="<?php echo $rows->nama ?>" />
                        </div>
```

I don't understand why CodeIgniter displays errors when I'm not using any of it's controllers or methods. So how to fix of my code ? Please

Comment: How do you expect us to find line 29?

Comment: `<input class="form-control" type="text" name="nama" value="<?php echo $rows->nama ?>" /> `

Comment: What is `$rows` variable? you didn't show the code for it.

Comment: $rows for get a detail  of data (`$data['rows']= $this->m_property->getByID($id);`)

Answer (score 0):

Check your code on line 29 (we don't know your entire file, thus we cannot spot that certain line).

But it is probably `$this->m_category` or `$this->m_property` holding a non [object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) value or null. Thus, you cant access any attribute nor method with `->`. This can also occurr in controllers, models or views, check that according to the failing reported file.

> you can var_dump() that variable to check its current contents. If you are loading it from database make sure it is not returning empty set, or that you have stored a an **object** and not an **array**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting some value in array and getting it in as object.
I think it is on your view file

nama ?>
replace it with
nama ?>

Answer (score 0):

in Model

```
public function getByID($id)
    {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM properti WHERE nID = '$id'");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
    }
```